# Use of facebook app has been restricted?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Without being logged into Facebook, when we open https://apps.facebook.com/gaanaworld/ url it shows error message (Use of app "Gaanaworld" has been restricted)
(Error while loading page from Gaanaworld)

But after logging in, it works fine. Please help as soon as possibly why it shows error message before login.

Comment: Sounds like you have country/age/alcohol restriction enabled in your app settings. Before the user logs in, Facebook can not determine whether or not they are allowed to see your app.

Comment: I see this too. I do not have alcohol or any other restrictions int he advanced settings.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Advanced, and make sure that "Let users without a location see my app" is not checked. This happened to me. I don't have any country selected, and had this checkbox ticked. Even though it seems like it should accept all users, it seems that FB needs user to be logged in before it knows that (s)he does not have a location. I.e. it seems that "no location" is not the same as "any location".